# Transform SMTP stream object to HTTP request

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I have written a code to host SMTP server using nodemailer in Nodejs. When I receive a SMTP data request to OnData event, I need the stream to be converted to a http request and redirect to another endpoint using axios.

```
onData(stream, session, callback) {
            
            mailparser(stream, {}, (err, parsed) => {
                if (err)
                    console.log('Error:', err);

                redirectMessage(session.envelope.rcptTo[0].address, parsed, app).then((response) => callback(response.status)).catch((error) => callback(error));

                stream.on('end', callback);
            });


const redirectMessage = async (to, mail, app) => {
    var endPoint = await franchiseService.getPushEndpointFromEmailList(to, app.locals.db);
    var referenceData = await franchiseService.getFranchisePersonalReferences(to, app.locals.db);
    if (!endPoint) {
        throw new Error('endpoint not found');
    }
    try {
        const apiResponse = await axios({
            headers: {
                'referenceType': referenceData[0]['PersonTypeID'],
                'referenceId': referenceData[0]['PersonID']
            },
            method: 'post',
            url: endPoint,
            data: mail,
        });

        return apiResponse;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
};
```